# C++ assign default hash function into member variable

Tags: c++, hash, variable-assignment, member

I'm creating a hashtable class and I have 2 constructors(one that takes no hash function/it uses the default one I create and another where it uses the hash function passed). Part of the code is as follows:

```
HEADER_FILE
class HashMap
{
public:
    typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction; //
    HashMap(HashFunction hashFunction); // These 4 lines are the focus of the question.
    HashMap();                          //
    HashMap(HashFunction hasher);       //
    ~HashMap(); 
    HashMap(const HashMap& hm);
    HashMap& operator=(const HashMap& hm);

private:
    HashFunction hasher
}
```

In my 2 constructors, I have this set up and I get an error saying `no viable overloaded '=' hasher = default_hasher`:

```
SOURCE_FILE
unsigned int default_hasher(std::string& k)
{
  performs (int) on each character in the string and adds them up. 
  Returns the total
}

HashMap::HashMap()
{
   hasher = default_hasher;
   ...
}

HashMap::HashMap(HashFunction hasher)
{
  hasher = hasher;
  ...
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your `default_hasher` use `const` for its parameter, since `HashFunction` specified so. Besides, it's the sensible thing to do, in the name of const-correctness.